# In Rails Erb how do I loop in desc order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, erb

Hi I am trying to create a news feed but I want the newest post to display at the top. So basically I want to display in desc order. I'm sure I could come up with a solution for this but I was wondering if any one knows of the best and easiest way like if there is a method already supplied by rails to do this?

```
<h3 class="title">News Feed</h3>
<div class="news-content">
  <% Post.all.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="title"><%= post.title %></div>
      <div class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime('%b %-d') %></div>
      <div class="content"><%= raw post.description %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you make use of scope.

Create scope `latest_first` in `Post` model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :latest_first, order('created_at DESC')
end
```

and use the scope in view

```
<h3 class="title">News Feed</h3>
<div class="news-content">
  <% Post.latest_first.find_each do |post| %>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="title"><%= post.title %></div>
      <div class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime('%b %-d') %></div>
      <div class="content"><%= raw post.description %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

you can give suitable name to scope based on its use

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to split the data-loading logic away into the controller ...

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.order(id: :desc)
  end
end
```

The controller layer specifies what data to load and how to do it. I also prefer to explicitly state the order using the ActiveRecord DSL. Then in your view you can just do ....

```
<h3 class="title">News Feed</h3>
<div class="news-content">
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="title"><%= post.title %></div>
      <div class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime('%b %-d') %></div>
      <div class="content"><%= raw post.description %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```